# How to set the request headers that i send in postman, but in the navigator?

Tags: express, request, header, jwt

In postman is a section where you can put or set a header. But how do i set it but in the navigator, that lasts over time through requests to different routes?

I´ve already tried setting a header, from the backend with differents methods like, and none of both worked:

```
res.header('x-token', jwt)
```

Or like

```
res.set('x-token', jwt)
```

And from the frontend i already tried with this methods and it didn´t work either:

```
const data = {id_token};
//let myHeaders = new Headers();
fetch(url, {
    method: 'POST',
    body: JSON.stringify(data),
    headers:{
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
  })
  .then(resp => resp.json())
  .then(({jwt}) => {

      if (jwt) {
        localStorage.setItem('x-token', jwt);

        //None of both worked
        //myHeaders.append('x-token', jwt);
        //myHeaders.set('x-token', jwt);
      }
  })
  .catch(error => console.error('Error:', error))
```

This is the header that i wanna send to the different routes:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ueoxu.png

Answer (score 0):

You can set the `x-token` header from your screen shot like this:

```
fetch(url, {
    method: 'POST',
    body: JSON.stringify(data),
    headers:{
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'x-token': 'eyJhbGciOiJIUzl.....'
    }
}).then(...).catch(...)
```

Comment: But the token is declarated after the headers. Besides that's what I return when I fetch the login, how do I set the header that lasts through the different routes?

Comment: @alfonsosarmie - I have no idea what that last comment means.  I'm having a hard time understanding exactly what you're asking.  There's no method of setting headers that last through multiple requests with `fetch()`.  You set them on each request you want to use them on.  You could make a shared function that always adds the same header.

Comment: @alfonsosarmie - In your screen shot, the token is one of the headers.  Order does not matter for http headers.